# HTMLcollection 0 list length, [n] returns undefined, converting to an array returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, svg

I'm making a ton of SVG elements using leaflet and d3.js. I've got a leaflet map, some divs below that, and then a script element where I'm populating the leaflet map, adding in data from .json files, and then attempting to tie event listeners to the divs below that add and remove classes to the svg elements. While trying to build a collection of the `<path>` elements I already made to iterate through them and add the class to them, but for the life of me I can't get a for loop working.

```
    var lowlightGisUnfiltered = document.getElementById(mapDivId).getElementsByClassName("gisData");
    console.log("unfiltered",lowlightGisUnfiltered, "length", lowlightGisUnfiltered.length);

    var transfer = lowlightGisUnfiltered;
    console.log("transfer:", transfer, "length:", transfer.length);

    var llarray = Array.prototype.slice.call(lowlightGisUnfiltered);
    console.log(llarray);

    console.log(lowlightGisUnfiltered[1]);
    console.log(transfer.item(1));

    var lowlightGIS = [];
    for(var n = 0; n < lowlightGisUnfilteredArray.length; n++){
        console.log("test");
        if(llarray[n].classList.contains(selectorClass)) {

            lowlightGIS.push(lowlightGisUnfiltered[n])
            }
    }
```

This outputs:

- unfiltered:[](a 580 element HTMLcollection that lists the length at the end as the correct length) length:0
- transfer: [](a 580 element HTMLcollection that lists the length at the end as the correct length) length:0
- [] (empty array)
- undefined
- null

All of that code is below the d3 and leaflet javascript where I'm making the dynamic tags.

I've checked all the other HTMLcollection or NodeList questions dealing with somewhat similar issues and they led to no solutions.

edit: I've also tried .querySelectorAll but that just returns an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my own question:

I didn't realize d3.json was asynchronous. My code was outside of the d3.json function so obviously my data wasn't actually loaded.